# How to save the history epochs and plots in files from keras models

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, matplotlib, colab

I have a question, that maybe is very simple, but I can't do it: I have 3 neural networks which are trained with 100 epochs, and I need to save all the history's train displayed at the end in a .txt file (i.e: time: 00s 0ms/step loss:... accuracy:... recall:... etc.), maybe it's easy, but also I need to plot each metric and its val_metric from each epoch and save that plots too, as images I guess (I know that maybe is nonsense to plot at epoch 1,2... but my professor ask us to do that). How can I do that? And, it's possible to save each line of the epoch and under it the correspondig plots in a file? I use Keras to build the model.
This is the `.compile()` function that I use:

```
   import tensorflow_addons as tfa
   residual_network_1d_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(
        name='accuracy', dtype=None, threshold=0.5),tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='Recall'),tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='Precision'),tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=27,average='macro'),
                    tf.keras.metrics.AUC(
        num_thresholds=200,
        curve="ROC",
        summation_method="interpolation",
        name="AUC",
        dtype=None,
        thresholds=None,
        multi_label=True,
        label_weights=None,
    )])
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data that is printed to the terminal while training you should be able to use the [`CSVLogger` callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/CSVLogger) which will save the output to a plain text file. For plotting the metrics you can use the metrics stored in the [History](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/History) object and plot them using a plotting library such as `matplotlib` and save them using the library specific function for saving the plot ([`matplotlib.pyplot.savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) for `matplotlib`).